# how to outline tab and content together

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I am trying to outline each tab with its content, but I can't achieve the wanted result. This is the code I have

```
$tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );

if ( ! empty( $tabs ) ) : ?>

    <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
        <ul class="tabs wc-tabs" role="tablist">
            <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
                <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>_tab" id="tab-title-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                    <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html( $tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
            <div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?> panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-title-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                <?php if ( isset( $tab['callback'] ) ) { call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ); } ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

How to style it properly that it looks like this ?
https://ibb.co/zX8Qwzb

[image: tab]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
ul.tabs li.active {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li {
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

However keep in mind that it is nearly impossible to provide a solution with the information you gave.